# Django Settings not configured

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I created a web project using Django and PyCharm, everything was working fine. When I reopened the project and added git, all the files were in red and when I tried to runserver I got a huge error message. The last error message is: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTING S_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Here is a screen shot:[You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHEoe.jpg)

I am trying to figure out why everything just stopped working.  Any help would be awesome. Thank you in advance.

L

Comment: Pass a flag with `--settings path.to.settings`

Comment: Are you running it in a different environment that doesn't have `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` defined?

Comment: I do not think I have changed anything from when it was working.  How do I make sure the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE are defined?

Comment: which tutorial did you follow to setup your project?  did they mention setting environment variables?  the error indicates that django cannot find the path to your settings.py file (which is usually explicitly defined, or is configured as an environment variable)  If you used "SET DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = xxxxx" and then closed the command prompt, it would lose that variable